# exporting a java project to a server using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compilation

I have made a program that parses a text file and then works with the reuslt. I now need to compile this so I can deploy it on a server. 2 things.

1) I want to be able to update the text file regularly...is this possible without recompiling every time?

2) when I compile it with eclipse, I get a jar. If I click it nothing seems to happen. Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it without recompiling the program every time.

Create an executable jar from eclipse.

Select your project> File> Export > Java> Runable Jar File.

Please specify the main class where the main method exist.

Now it you click on this jar file , your program will be executed.

**Note: If your program does not have any user interface, you will not see anything. When you will click on the jar program will be executed and immediate finished.**

Comment: will this put the text files into a folder alongside the jar or something? update- tried this and it doesn't work. The jar doesn't make the program run and it doesn't seem to make a folder or anything storing the text file. Thanks though.

Comment: you can load the text file from the current working directory where the jar file reside. Dont provide any full path just provide the file name when reading file. In that case it will load the file from current directory of the jar file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it still doesn't seem  to work. Is there anyway to debug a jar, find out why it isnt doing as expected?

Comment: I think you did something wrong. It should work because I'm doing similar thing. You can post your code here

Comment: what is your problem now? Is the jar is not executing? If yes. Right click on the jar  then open with then select javaw from your jre installation folder

Comment: I just click it and nothing seems to happen.